# Is "coachee" even a word?

Tags: word-choice, is-it-a-word, er-ee

If I am Rita's coach, is Rita my *coachee? (yikes) Is that even a word?
Would it be correct instead to say she is my ward? What about terms for people at the other end of a mentor, sponsor relationship?

Comment: This has started being used at my work. Thank you for asking the question for me.

Comment: _'...ee'_ is usually paired with an _'..er'_, isn't it? Employee/Employer, Trainee/Trainer. I wouldn't use _Coachee_ because to me, it implies you're a _Coacher_, not a Coach.

Comment: But mentoring and coaching are two different skills. So therefore could not be refered to as mentee if being coached.

Comment: Coachee seems very stilted to me. After hearing the term used excessively during a four hour class, I picture a coachee as some kind of rare, hothouse flower that needs extensive nurturing.

Answer (score 5):

[*Coachee*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Coachee) is indeed a valid word, but often not widely used. I would suggest *pupil* or *trainee* instead.

Comment: The [OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0157770?rskey=63BCYC&result=2#m_en_gb0157770) reports that _coach_ means "an instructor or trainer in sport"; in that case, I would not use _pupil_.

Comment: That's not the only meaning of *coach* (as a title) though. We also have concepts like ["life coach"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaching).

Answer (score 3):

You need to qualify the terms to find suitable counterparts.

If you are Rita's *coach* (sports) then Rita might be a *member of your team*.

If you are Rita's *guardian* (parental) then Rita might be your *ward*.

If you are Rita's *mentor* then Rita might be your *trainee* (in education) or *disciple* (spiritual).

**Update:** @Malvolio suggests protégé, which I think is the best answer so far.

Comment: *mentee* has also gained quite a bit of ground, recently.

Comment: God, I hate `mentee`.  The word is `protégé`.

Comment: @Malvolio - protégé is probably the best answer. Add it as an answer and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

*Coachee* indeed is a valid word.

Alternately, you could use [student](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Marx).

Answer (score 1):

'Protégé' is the word you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In a sports context, Rita is *your athlete*.  The possessive should make it clear enough what the relationship is.

Answer (score 0):

When the word "coach" is used to mean "guide" (as in a business environment), the person being guided is a "follower," but the follower is really an employee. So, as someone who is always willing to push the envelope with language, I propose a new word for the employee who is being coached/guided: emplayee. Now I know this will not catch on, but I just had a little bit of fun. Think about it: when you are an emplOyee, you are going round and round in that "O" doing your job and maybe spinning it a little off-track every now and then. When you are an emplAyee, you are on your way to a lesson from your boss/manager/coach and you want to get an A, like you used to do in school in the classes you loved.

Thank you!